# NODE/EXPRESS/BODY-PARSER não estou conseguindo ler o body, fica dando UNDEFINED

Tags: node.js, express.js, body

Bom vou postar a index aqui para vocês darem uma olhada, eu refiz o código e funcionou com outro proposito, mas com esse proposito de pegar as informações e mandar pro banco de dados sempre da undefined, não sei oque poderia ser.

```
insira o código aqui
const porta = 3003
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const bd = require('./callBd.js')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/user', (req, res) =>{
    bd.execQuery('SELECT * FROM User', res);
})

app.get('/user/:id?',(req,res) => {
    bd.execQuery(`SELECT * FROM User where ID = ${req.params.id}`, res);
})


app.post('/user/:user?/:prof?/:pass?', (req, res) =>{
    const name = req.body.nome
    const prof = req.body.profissao
    const pass = req.body.password
    /**const name = req.params.user
    const prof = req.params.prof
    const pass = req.params.pass**/

    console.log(name,prof,pass)
    bd.execQuery(`INSERT INTO User(Name, Profission, Password) VALUES('${name}','${prof}','${pass}')`, res);
});

app.listen(porta,()=>{
   console.log(`Servidor está executando na porta ${porta}.`)
})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: JÁ TENTEI USAR AS OUTRAS OPÇÕES COMO RAW NA POSTMAN MAIS TODAS DEVOLVEM UNDEFINED]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa tarde.

Na opção de "Body", do Postman, marque a opção "row", e no lado esquerdo vai aparecer ao opção do tipo de "Body". Clique nele e selecione a opção "JSON (application/json)".

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]